# How to upload a large file as chunk in azure media service using only c#?

Tags: c#, azure-media-services, chunks

I was trying to upload files into azure media service(console application), if the file size is less i can use normal upload method as follows

```
static public IAsset CreateAssetAndUploadSingleFile(AssetCreationOptions assetCreationOptions, string singleFilePath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(singleFilePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File does not exist.");
            return null;
        }

        var assetName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(singleFilePath);
        IAsset inputAsset = _context.Assets.Create(assetName, assetCreationOptions);

        var assetFile = inputAsset.AssetFiles.Create(Path.GetFileName(singleFilePath));

        Console.WriteLine("Upload {0}", assetFile.Name);

        assetFile.Upload(singleFilePath);
        Console.WriteLine("Done uploading {0}", assetFile.Name);

        return inputAsset;
    }
```

this will upload the file into azure media service, but if the file size is too large,  want to split it into chunks and need to upload, what changes should i make to achieve this only using c#.

i have seen a link which explain this using javascript(i have no idea) [gaurav's link](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/). how can i implement similar using c#.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this article already?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-dotnet-upload-files#upload-multiple-files-with-media-services-net-sdk

Look at the section on uploading multiple files. It allows you to adjust the number of threads used by the BobTransferClient built into the SDK

```
 var blobTransferClient = new BlobTransferClient();
        blobTransferClient.NumberOfConcurrentTransfers = 20;
        blobTransferClient.ParallelTransferThreadCount = 20;
```

Comment: its about multiple files ryt, mt case is single file slitting and uploading. at the end it should be a single file only.

Comment: The blob client does split a single file up into block blob chunks. We only support block blobs,and that uploader code does parallel chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would also be to just get a SAS URL to upload directly into the container in Blob Storage, and then use the Azure Storage Net Data movement library that is used as the underlying component of the AzCopy tool.  This allows you to completely control the parallel uploads, chunks sizes, concurrent threads, etc.  Gives you all the power and the knobs!

https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement